# Can't run VBoxLinuxAdditions.run on opensuse using virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, kernel, opensuse

I'm trying to run the VBoxLinuxAdditions.run file, following the solution presented here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/321589/unable-to-mount-the-cd-dvd-image-on-the-machine-sandbox

However I get a message saying

> kernel headers not found for target kernel

I have tried fixing this by installing `linux-headers-generic` however my terminal says that it could not find the package. The same happens when I try to install a basic package like build-essentials.
I have checked whether my main repository is active and up to date and it is. Any idea on what went wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by:

zypper in kernel-devel

(Make sure kernel and kernel-devel are on the same level